# Unknown reason why I get PDO Invalid Parameter Error

Tags: php, pdo

I dont understand what I am doing wrong with my function?

I'm trying Example #2 on this page http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php but tells me there an invalid parameter number. But I dont get why it work?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
$sql = "SELECT challenge FROM challenges WHERE sessionid=':sessionid' AND timestamp > :timestamp LIMIT 1;";
$params = array(':sessionid'=>session_id(), ':timestamp'=>time());

function pdoRS($sql, $params) {
    try {
        // Prepare Query
        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(($params!=""?$params:NULL));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Output error
        echo 'Execution Exception: '.$e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
}

print_r(pdoRS($sql,params));
```

Even if I change it to:

```
    $sql = "SELECT challenge FROM im_accounts_challenges WHERE sessionid='?' AND timestamp > ? AND isauthenticated=1 LIMIT 1;";
    $params = array(session_id(), time());
```

I still get the same message:

```
Execution Exception: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Comment: why use `'?'` and `':sessionid'`? please remove quotes around parameters (stakeholders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepared statements use `?` and `:something` as placeholders for the real data *regardless* of its type. In other way, there's no need to quote the strings here:

```
SELECT challenge FROM im_accounts_challenges WHERE sessionid = ?
```

... as that'll be done automatically when data will be supplied.

What you're doing here...

```
SELECT challenge FROM im_accounts_challenges WHERE sessionid = '?'
```

... is telling SQL to find all the rows where `sessionid` is equal to a *literal* `'?'`. That's allowed, because sometimes you *do* need to use fixed-strings criteria - even when working with prepared statements.

Now, `'?'` is treated as a literal, so there's no more placeholders in the statement - and any attempt to bind them will give the warning you've seen.